# Getting bad instructions error when compiling the following code in assembly

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi3, gpio, instructions, wiringpi

I am working on a raspberry pi at the moment and I am running into an issue with my assembly code. When i try to run it with the following command:

```
     as button.o button.s
```

in terminal. An the following errors occur:

```
Assembler messages:
Error: can't open button.o for reading: No such file or directory
button.s:6: Error: bad instruction `errmsg .asciz "Setup didn't work... 
Aborting...\n"'
button.s:7: Error: bad instruction `pinup .int 3'
button.s:8: Error: bad instruction `pinleft .int 14'
button.s:9: Error: bad instruction `pindown .int 0'
button.s:10: Error: bad size 0 in type specifier
button.s:10: Error: bad instruction `pinright.int 7'
button.s:11: Error: bad instruction `pinpau .int 15'
button.s:12: Error: bad instruction `pinqu .int 2'
button.s:32: Error: bad instruction `blwiringpisetup'
button.s:48: Error: bad arguments to instruction -- `mov r7#1'
button.s:50: Error: bad instruction `be done'
```

I'm not sure if it is a syntax error or or a problem with the code in general.
The code follows:

```
//data Section

        .data
        .balign 4
Intro:  .asciz  "Raspberry Pi - Blinking led test inassembly\n"
ErrMsg  .asciz  "Setup didn't work... Aborting...\n"
pinUp   .int    3
pinLeft .int    14
pinDown .int    0
pinRight.int    7
pinPau  .int    15
pinQu   .int    2
i:  .int    0


//Code section

    .text
    .global main
    .extern printf
    .extern wiringPiSetup
    .extern delay
    .extern digitalRead
    .extern pinMode

main:   push    {ip, lr}
// printf message
    ldr r0, =Intro
    bl  printf

//Check for setup error
    blwiringPiSetup
    mov     r1,#-1
    cmp r0, r1
    bne init
    ldr r0, =ErrMsg
    bl  printf
    b   done
init:
    ldr r0, =pinUp
    ldr r1, =pinLeft
    ldr r2, =pinDown
    ldr r3, =pinRight
    ldr r4, =pinPau
    ldr r5, =pinQu

    mov r6, #1
    mov r7  #1
    cmp r6, r7
    be  done

done:
    pop {ip,pc}
```

Followed variable decleration of the following code:

```
//---------------------------------------
//  Data Section
// ---------------------------------------




          .data
          .balign 4 
Intro:   .asciz  "Raspberry Pi - Blinking led test in assembly\n"
ErrMsg:  .asciz "Setup didn't work... Aborting...\n"
pin:     .int   0
i:       .int   0
delayMs: .int   1000
OUTPUT   =      1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you clear your registers before you use them? Are you sure r7 doesn't already contain a value? Are you aloud to use r7?

Comment: Could also be a problem with this button.o.

Comment: When i try to clear the registers r6 and r7 i get:
    button.s:47: Error: bad instruction `clr r6'
    button.s:48: Error: bad instruction `clr r7'

Comment: My understanding is that is the file the assembler will create.

Comment: Where might i find which registers I can use. I am having trouble finding it.

Comment: Although not your problem I think you mean to do `as -o button.o button.s` `-o` is followed by the output file name.

Comment: You may have missed the part "Although not your problem". What I suggested wouldn't solve the bad instructions it should fix the issue with `Error: can't open button.o for reading: No such file or directory` . Without the `-o` in front of `button.o` the file is also being treated as an input file.

Comment: I missed it the first time when I looked at the code, but *most* of your label names aren't terminated with a colon. For example `ErrMsg  .asciz  "Setup didn't work... Aborting...\n"` should be `ErrMsg:  .asciz  "Setup didn't work... Aborting...\n"` . You make a similar error on most of your labels. You did get it correct when you defined `Intro` and `i`

Comment: @Michael Petch
I am incredibly embarrassed. Are you experienced in using wiringPi by any chance.

Comment: No I'm not - sorry

Answer (score 1):

**You forgot the colon after your label names, so the parser was treating them as instruction mnemonics.  `ErrMsg:` instead of `ErrMsg`**.

Also, put read-only data normally goes in `.rodata`, not `.data`.  You could put it in `.data` if you want it near something else so you can address them all from one base address, though, instead of using a totally separate `ldr` for every label.  (You could generate addresses in registers with `add`, instead of loading a separate literal.)

```
.section .rodata
  @ .balign 4   @ why align before strings?  Normally you'd pad for alignment *after*, unless the total string length is a multiple of 4 bytes or something.
  Intro:  .asciz  "Raspberry Pi - Blinking led test inassembly\n"
  ErrMsg:  .asciz  "Setup didn't work... Aborting...\n"

.data
    .balign 4
    pinUp:    .int    3
    pinLeft:  .int    14
    pinDown:  .int    0     @ zero-int vars could be placed in the .bss
    pinRight: .int    7
    pinPau:   .int    15
    pinQu:    .int    2

    i:  .int    0     @ do you really need / want  static int i  in your program?
                      @ Use a register for a loop counter.
```

Comment: Surprisingly, googling on the error message, or that + `label` or `colon` didn't find any duplicates.  So I guess this is worth answering in case anyone else in the future has the same error.